# Select links in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I'm looking to do the following:

1. Locate links in the document
2. Select them and change their styling

So far, I have:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var text = body.editAsText().getText();
var words = text.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  var word = words[i];
  // Doesn't work because word isn't a Text object
  // word.getLinkUrl();
}
```

I understand how to [iterate over the words in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971423/google-apps-script-iterating-through-words-in-a-paragraph). The issue is determining if the text is a link. I can't use the `getText()` method because that converts the Text object to a string (prohibiting me from testing if a word is a link via the `getLinkUrl()` method.

I've found a number of "find and replace" solutions. I can't use `findText()` because I can't predict the strings in the links. For instance, *Resources* could point to *example.com*.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to improve your question.  How do you want to style the links?  Have you tried to write a function that just styles a link?  That seems to be the block.

Comment: Styling the links is a non-issue. The problem is that I can't select the links that are currently in the document. Updating the question now.